# 'Authorization' header returning nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a test that sets the Authorization header.

```
  test "index should return a list of shifts at a given date" do
    @request.env["Custom_authorization"] = "bar"
    @request.env["Authorization"] = "bar"
    get :index,
        { date: '2015/9/8' }

    assert_response :success
  end
```

For some reason, the 'Authorization' header is being set to nil, even though customer authorization headers are set:

```
(byebug) request.headers['Authorization']
nil
(byebug) request.headers['Custom_authorization']
"bar"
```

Where is the 'Authorization' header being set to nil?

Answer (score 1):

get method prototype is,

```
 get(path, parameters = nil, headers_or_env = nil)
```

Reff : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Integration/RequestHelpers.html#method-i-get

So use it like,

```
get :index, { date: '2015/9/8' }, { "Authorization" => "bar" }
```

Answer (score 0):

This below should work
    (byebug) request.headers[:Authorization]